# Need a regex expert to match nested brackets

Tags: php, regex, recursion

A string :

```
Démontrer par récurrence que pour tout entier naturel n,\(\displaystyle{1^2+2^2+\ldots+n^2=\sum_{k=0\dfrac dsdq ds}rr^{n}k^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}}\)Démontrer par récurrence que pour tout entier naturel n,\(\displaystyle{1^2+2^2+\ldots+n^2=\sum_{k=0\dfrac{test} fdfd}^{n}k^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}}\)
```

I need to replace \dfrac with \frac in _{...} or ^{...}

I tried a lot of patterns (in vain) like :

```
/(_|\^)\{(.*[^{}])(\\dfrac)(.*[^{}])}/gU
```

Comment: No expert can help you if you are using a regex engine that does not support recursion or balancing groups. TL;DR: what tool/language are you using?

Comment: PCRE i think, i use php preg_replace function

Comment: I suggest to use the classical way to match nested brackets https://regex101.com/r/tO9fY2/1 with a callback `preg_replace_callback()` https://eval.in/private/ee0ac1d7c07cad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use preg_replace_callback, with a pattern able to extract content between `_{` and `}` or `^{` and `}` with nested curly brackets, and a callback function that will replace all occurrences of `\dfrac` in the match. Example:

```
$pattern = '~[_^]({[^{}]*(?:(?1)[^{}]*)*})~';

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern,
    function ($m) { return str_replace('\dfrac', '\frac', $m[0]); },
    $text);
```

pattern details:

```
~              # pattern delimiter
[_^]           # _ or ^
(              # open the capture group 1
    {
    [^{}]*     # all that is not a curly bracket
    (?:        # open a non capturing group
        (?1)   # the recursion is here:
               # (?1) refers to the subpattern contained in capture group 1
               # (so the current capture group)
        [^{}]* # 
    )*         # repeat the non capturing group as needed
    }
)              # close the capture group 1
~
```

Note: if curly brackets are not always balanced, you can change quantifiers to possessive to prevent too much backtracking and to make the pattern fail faster:

```
$pattern = '~[_^]({[^{}]*+(?:(?1)[^{}]*)*+})~';
```

or you can use an atomic group as well (or better):

```
$pattern = '~[_^]({(?>[^{}]*(?:(?1)[^{}]*)*)})~';
```

Comment: Is there any possible reason to hide the explanation instead of inlining the comments with `/x` mode?  Compressed line-noise style regexes are not maintainable.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't use the free-spacing/verbose/etc. mode for small patterns. Furthermore, there is no need to maintain this because, if you know the concept behind this kind of pattern, you are able to rewrite it from scratch to fit other needs, in the other case whatever the presentation, you can't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this regex:

```
(?(DEFINE)                            # Definitions
(?<needle>\\dfrac(?=[^\}]*\}))    # What to search for
(?<skip>^[^\{]*\{|\}[^\{]*\{)               # What we should skip
)
(?&skip)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)                # Skip it
|
(?&needle)                            # Match it
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rE0nN5/5).

PHP code:

```
$re = "/(?(DEFINE)                            # Definitions
        (?<needle>\\\\dfrac(?=[^\\}]*\\}))    # What to search for
        (?<skip>^[^\\{]*\\{|\\}[^\\{]*\\{)               # What we should skip
        )
        (?&skip)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)                # Skip it
        |
        (?&needle)                            # Match it/xm"; 
$str = "Démontrer par récurrence que pour tout entier naturel n,\n\dfrac\n\(\displaystyle{1^2+2^2+\ldots+n^2=\sum_{k=0\dfrac dsdq ds}rr^{n}k^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}}\)\nDémontrer par récurrence que pour tout entier naturel n,\n\n\(\displaystyle{1^2+2^2+\ldots+n^2=\sum_{k=0\dfrac{test} fdfd}^{n}k^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}}\)\n\n\dfrac"; 
$subst = "\\frac"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: One fail: https://regex101.com/r/rE0nN5/3 . IMHO the skip/fail trick isn't really useful in this particular case

Comment: @HamZa: It works now :) What have you been thinking of? Please post.

Comment: Thinking about your solution? It seems a bit clumsy/cryptic. Well it's regex after all lol. I'm still not convinced about this solution. It works though. Just be careful when you use `^`,  you probably want to use the `m` modifier and prevent the negative character classes from matching newlines in some contexts. +1 for now

Comment: @HamZa: Thank you for your comments. I see your point, and added the `m` inline option to enforce multiline behavior.