# What can I leverage (from R) to convert expressions with nested fractions from infix-notation to LaTeX?

Tags: r, latex, infix-notation

I'd like something to convert pretty basic math expressions, having nested parentheses and fractions, to LaTeX notation. Like [mathquill](http://mathquill.com), but a function (or even the building blocks of one).

There seem to be some [Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52221946/rendering-equations-as-images-and-including-them-in-word-powerpoint-output-docum) and [Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/latex-formulae-pandoc) solutions in a pandoc/Rmarkdown context, but I can't use those, because (a) I'm scared of real languages, and (b) I'm generating PNGs (via [webtex](https://latex.codecogs.com)) to be featured in a [flextable](https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/) table, outside of a rendered document.

I'm inexperienced with regular expressions, so I don't know how to leverage something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29604793/need-a-regex-expert-to-match-nested-brackets), but I'd appreciate any pointers if that seems like a productive path.

"Write a parser" is something best left to others, at least in my case!

Example expression below. Just a few levels of nesting, no big deal. I can bound it at, say, 5 levels, if that helps. And the input is parseable as an R expression—I can guarantee matched parentheses, for example.

```
(y0 - (y0/((1-y0)*exp(B*dx)+y0)))*Pop
```

Here's what I'd want in the case above. The `\cdot`s are sugar; I can handle those.

```
\left(y0-\frac{y0}{\left(1-y0\right)\cdot\exp\left(B\cdot dx\right)+y0}\right)\cdot Pop
```

Visually:

[image: (y0 - (y0/((1-y0)exp(Bdx)+y0)))*Pop]